# How to monitor a folder and trigger a command-line action when a file is created

Tags: powershell

I need to trigger a command-line action when a file is created in folder.
In my case when i create `n` - files in the folder the script starts `.cmd` `n` - times.
How to start the `.cmd` script only ones when i have multiple created files?

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\fso"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.xls"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { Start-Process cmd.exe "/c D:\Users\xfirebg\Desktop\excel\append.cmd"
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 20}
```

Comment: When you write multiple files in a directory at the same time, the events happens one by one. If you are not interrested in each event, why don't you poll the directory every n seconds. Another solution is two start your process every n events and not on each event.

Comment: Yes, how to do the second solution?

Comment: the first solusion is not un option because the cmd script converting the xls to pdf and move it(xls) to another folder. After this user again creating xls files in the fso folder. So in this folder i always have pdfs.

Comment: I wish to monitor if any xls file is in this folder. Then my cmd script is starting once to do his job for all xls files i.e converting xls files

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-Wait` option with the `Start-Process` cmdlet; this should force the script to wait until your command has finished executing:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\fso"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.xls"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { Start-Process -Wait cmd.exe "/c D:\Users\xfirebg\Desktop\excel\append.cmd"
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 20}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the script still runs multiple times if someone moves more then one file into the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to start your process every n events and not on each event.

I use an object as parameter, that I receive in each call.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\temp"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.tmp"
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
      Write-host "coucou $($event.MessageData.counter)";
      $event.MessageData.counter +=1
      if ($event.MessageData.counter % 3 -eq 0){
        Write-host "Bingo !"
      }
    }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{"counter" = 0}
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action -SourceIdentifier "test" -MessageData $obj
Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "test"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is interesting. But its not for my case. What if user copy one  or two files in the folder? The script will not start. I need the script to start only ones if there is one or multiple files in the folder.

Comment: My mayor problem is that. When .cmd script starts multiple times in short period of time  they are in conflict each other. I need to get more time to finish the job of the .cmd script